# App Recovery - Decompiling Android Project Classes From APK

Tags: android, class, apk, decompiling, recovery

I am currently working on an android app but my hard drive unfortunately crashed and I lost all the data on it... I am trying to recover my source code from the debug APK I had installed on my phone (using dex2jar and jd-gui) however, it seems like the classes are not present in the classes.dex and classes2.dex (both files are tiny and do not contain any of the classes in my code, see photo).

I used apk extractor to get the apk from my installed app and I cant seem to get anything close to my original classes... I am wondering if I am doing something wrong to get the APK from the installed app; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: classes2.dex]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For de-compiling your APK to Java classes you can go to this site - 
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

Just upload your apk and click on decompile. It should work for you !

Comment: thank you, i tried it as well but im still not able to get classes in any way... i wonder if it has to do with the apk being a debug version from android studio (and not an actual exported packaged apk)